# React Functional Component: How to prevent form from submitting if validation failed

Tags: reactjs

I need some help, I am new to react. I created a Functional Component form with Context API and I am trying to prevent it from submitting if the form failed validation and return false. I have check the validation and it is working by uncommenting the html input button and comment out the React Link (`<Link></Link>`) button. I try the code with class component and **bind the `handleChange` and `handleSubmit`** inside the constructor and it work: however, I do not want to used the class component. I just want to used the function component.

```js
const Employee = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(FormActualContext);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    ctx.handleChange({
      event,
      type: 'employee',
    });
  };

  const validate = () => {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      dateOfBirth,
      phoneNum,
    } = ctx.formData.employee;
    const { employee } = ctx.formErrors;
    let {
      firstNameError,
      lastNameError,
      emailError,
      dateOfBirthError,
      phoneNumError,
    } = employee;

    firstNameError = !firstName ? 'First name can not be blank' : '';
    lastNameError = lastName === '' ? 'Last name can not be blank' : '';
    dateOfBirthError = !dateOfBirth ? 'Enter a valid date of birth' : '';
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      emailError =
        email === '' ? 'Enter a valid email' : `${email} is not valid email`;
    } else {
      emailError = '';
    }
    if (!validatePhoneNumber(phoneNum)) {
      phoneNumError =
        phoneNum === ''
          ? 'Enter a valid phone'
          : `${phoneNum} is not a valid phone number`;
    } else {
      phoneNumError = '';
    }

    if (
      firstNameError ||
      lastNameError ||
      emailError ||
      dateOfBirthError ||
      phoneNumError
    ) {
      ctx.setFormErrors({
        employee: {
          ...employee,
          firstNameError,
          lastNameError,
          emailError,
          dateOfBirthError,
          phoneNumError,
        },
      });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isValid = validate();
    if (isValid) {
      ctx.reSetEmployee();
    }
  };
  const {
    employee: {
      firstNameError,
      lastNameError,
      emailError,
      dateOfBirthError,
      phoneNumError,
    },
  } = ctx.formErrors;
  return (
    <div className="container_fluid">
      <div className="registration_form_container">
        <div className="register_context">
          <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="registration_form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                id="firstName"
                placeholder={'Enter first name'}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <span>{firstNameError}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lastName"
                id="lastName"
                placeholder={'Enter last name'}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <span>{lastNameError}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                placeholder={'Enter email address'}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <span>{emailError}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="date"
                name="dateOfBirth"
                id="dateOfBirth"
                placeholder={'Enter date of birth'}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <span>{dateOfBirthError}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="phoneNum"
                id="phoneNum"
                placeholder={'Enter phone number (international: +1)'}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <span>{phoneNumError}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group custom_btn_container">
              {/*<input type="submit" className="btn" value="Register"/>*/}
              <Link to="/addressForm">
                <input type="submit" className="btn" value="Register" />
              </Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue isn't that the form is being submitted upon validation (true or false), but rather that both field validation **and** route navigation are more or less occurring at the same time. The `Link`, upon being clicked, will immediately navigate to the specified path.

## Solution

Seems you want to validate the input, and only upon successful validation, call the `reSetEmployee` function on the context and navigate to "/addressForm".

I suggest rendering the submit button ***not*** within a `Link` and use imperative navigation. For this I'm assuming you are using `react-router-dom` library.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();

...

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const isValid = validate();
  if (isValid) {
    ctx.reSetEmployee();
    history.push("/addressForm");
  }
};

...

<div className="form-group custom_btn_container">
  <input type="submit" className="btn" value="Register"/>
</div>
```